# "Добавочное действие совершает другой субъект" - помогите перестроить предложение!

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастия

> И вот глядя на такой искренний испуг моей Нянюшки, всякие истории
>   вихрем пролетели у меня в голове.

Нянюшка - персонаж. Алёнушка реплику забыла, а Н. думает, не поплохело ли А.

Я что-то авторское непременно испорчу, если нарисую:

*Когда я увидела такой искренний испуг на лице своей Нянюшки...*

Другой глагол нужен, с оттенком внезапности и оторопи, вроде:

*Когда я споткнулась о такой искренний испуг...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меня так ошеломил неподдельный испуг на лице моей Нянюшки, что в голове замелькали всякие истории.

Comment: Спасибо, но как раз вторую часть предложения, мне кажется, автор не "отдаст"... Не подкинете ли ещё вариантика?

Comment: _От одного лишь взгляда на испуганное лицо... у меня в голове вихрем..._ Главное, отговорить автора от "глядя на испуг, у меня вихрем слетела шляпка" :)

Answer (score 2):

*Из-за очевидно искреннего испуга в глазах Нянюшки всякие истории вихрем пролетели у меня в голове.* Как-то так.

Comment: Это мысль. Но нуждающаяся в редактуре. ))) Всё предложенное оставить, выкинуть *очевидно*.

Answer (score 1):

**И как следствие такого искреннего испуга на лице моей Нянюшки**, всякие истории вихрем пролетели у меня в голове.